# background-attachment:fixed; on mobile Safari

Tags: css, parallax

I'm trying to work with the nice parallax effect in this template. It seems to work well with all browsers except mobile Safari (unusually)!

http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB002R8U1

Look at the ABOUT and FOURTH sections on an iPad and the background image goes missing (presumably because it's stuck to the top of the page behind the other elements.

Anyone know a workaround for this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

parallax on mobile iOS is not that easy: safari blocks all rendering while scrolling (for performance boosting), therefore you can't measure the current scrolled distance and apply it to the background position. the picture would only refresh it's position when you've finished scrolling (and without animation, so you wouldn't see anything of it).

There are workarounds but they're not as easy to implement. one of them is http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/ with its [iOS techdemo](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/demos/ios.html).

Best solution: split your css markup and let parallax only be visible to desktop devices. As parallax needs a lot of power (because it's not hardware accelerated), it's not very suitable for mobile devices anyway.